# Understanding kernel patch submitting check list?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

There is one check list regarding submitting patches for kernel
"Passes allnoconfig, allmodconfig".

I am not able to compile fresh kernel code with allmodeconfig, below are steps I am using for testing this checklist : -

```
make allmodconfig
make
```

Please correct my understanding ,Any other information and resources related to this will be appreciated.

Comment: What step is failed and what error message is shown?

Comment: @Tsyvarev scripts/sign-file.c:20: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/sign-file] Error 1
make: *** [scripts] Error 2

Comment: @Tsyvarev steps followed 1) downloaded stable kernel form git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git 2)make allmodconfig and then make

Comment: Do you have the OpenSSL (development) package installed?

Comment: Seems you miss the openssl-dev package (naming depends of your distribution)

Comment: @CL.  Thank you I have missed installation of openssl-dev package

Comment: @Mali  Thank you I have missed installation of openssl-dev package